# What is the first step in debugging this model and how?

Tags: oop, debugging, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Debugging within OpenModelica seems to grow harder and harder the more I learn about it and realize how little of experience I have.

I have been reading a lot of OpenModelica Debugging literature and most pieces only seems to scrape the surface on debugging. The most helpful piece I have read was "Tools and Methods for Analysis, Debugging, and Performance Improvement of Equation-Based Models" by Martin Sjolund, a very prominent figure within the Modelica Community. Unfortunately, I do not have the background/experience to be able to follow all of Dr. Sjlund's book.
Even the OpenModelica users guide seems to barely iterate throughout the debugging process and the rest is to figure out on the users end.

I never know what to expect after my model successfully 1. checks and 2. flattens (instantiates). The algorithmic debugger is still a mystery to me.

EDIT: Code of model I'm having issues with

model HRSG_WaterDrum_HXVersion

///Current Version: Phase State: Left to be interpreted/guessed. This can be switched back. Volume should also be explored . . . Volumes taken from Library Model are very small with respect to small mass flow rate. Current Version: V & SA = 1///

```
ThermoPower.Water.Drum Drum(
Cm = 4.08e6 * 1.195e-2, 
DrumOrientation = 1, 
Kcs = 0.01, 
Ks = 100, 
L = 1.455, 
afd = 0.0, 
gl = 300, 
gv = 150, 
hlstart = 203.22e3, 
hvstart = 203.22e3, 
lm = 19, 
pstart = 
100e5, 
rext = 0.125, 
rint = 0.115, 
tauc = 5, 
tauev = 15)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-49, 3}, extent = 
{{-21, -21}, {21, 21}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkMassFlow Blowdown annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, -32}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.Flow1DFV2ph Downcomer(
A = 1.903e-3, 
Cfnom = 0.01, 
Dhyd = 0.04922, 
DynamicMomentum = false, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Colebrook, 
H = -15.923, 
Kfc = 1, 
L = 15.923, 
N = 2, 
dpnom = 100, 
e = 6.1e-4, 
hstartin = 1407.6e3, 
hstartout = 1407.6e3, 
omega = 0.1546, 
pstart = 100e5, 
wnf = 0.3, 
wnom = 21.5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-64, -50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Thermal.MetalTubeFV Downcomer_Wall(
L = 15.923, 
Nw = 1, 
Tstart1 = 540, 
TstartN = 540, 
WallRes = true, 
lambda = 19, 
rext = 0.03015, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rint = 0.02461)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-48, -50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

ThermoPower.Water.Header HeaderLower(
Cm = 4.08e6 * 4.51e-4, 
S = 1, 
Tmstart = 540, 
V = 1, 
gamma = 2000, 
hstart = 1407.6e3, 
noInitialPressure = true, 
pstart = 101.18e5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-30, -96}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.PressDrop PressureDrop(
A = 5.62e-5, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.PressDrop.FFtypes.Kinetic, 
K = 3, 
Kfc = 2, 
dpnom = 80000, 
wnf = 0.1, 
wnom = 21.5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {38, -96}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.Header HeaderUpper(
Cm = 4.08e6 * 4.51e-4,
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.TwoPhases, 
S = 1, 
Tmstart = 311.1 + 273.15, 
V = 1, 
gamma = 2000, 
hstart = 2724.7e3, 
noInitialPressure = true, 
pstart = 100.2e5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {72, -36}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

ThermoPower.Water.Flow1DFV2ph Pipe2Drum(
A = 5.557e-4, 
Cfnom = 0.01, 
Dhyd = 0.0266, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
H = 2.779, 
HydraulicCapacitance = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Upstream, 
L = 2.779, 
N = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
dpnom = 17000, 
e = 9.9e-4, 
hstartin = 2724.7e3, 
hstartout = 2724.7e3, 
noInitialPressure = true, 
omega = 0.0835, 
pstart = 100e5, 
wnf = 0.1, 
wnom = 21.5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {19, -9}, extent = 
{{-11, 11}, {11, -11}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Thermal.MetalTubeFV Pipe2Drum_Wall(
L = 2.779, 
Nw = 1, 
Tstart1 = 584.25, 
TstartN = 584.25, 
WallRes = true, 
lambda = 19, 
rext = 0.0167, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rint = 0.0133)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {19, 9}, extent = {{-11, 
-11}, {11, 11}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Water.Flow1DFV2ph Pipe2SH(
A = 3.301 - 4, 
Cfnom = 0.004, 
Dhyd = 0.0205, 
DynamicMomentum = false, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
H = 0, 
HydraulicCapacitance = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream, 
L = 11.48, 
N = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
dpnom = 2000, 
hstartin = 2724.7e3, 
hstartout = 2724.7e3, 
omega = 0.0644, 
pstart = 100e5, 
wnom = 0.06)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-20, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Thermal.MetalTubeFV Pipe2SH_Wall(
L = 11.480, 
Nw = 1, 
Tstart1 = 584.25, 
TstartN = 584.25, 
WallRes = true, 
lambda = 19, 
rext = 0.01305, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rint = 0.01025)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-20, 66}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Water.ValveVap VaporValve(
Av = 2.7e-5, 
CvData = ThermoPower.Choices.Valve.CvTypes.Av, 
dpnom = 2e+06, 
pnom = 95e5, 
useThetaInput = true, 
wnom = 2 * 0.06)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {70, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Thermal.MetalTubeFV Pipe2Valve_Wall(
L = 6.6, 
Nw = 1, 
Tstart1 = 633.15, 
TstartN = 633.15, 
WallRes = true, 
lambda = 19, 
rext = 0.01275, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rint = 0.0100)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {40, 66}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Water.Flow1DFV2ph Pipe2Valve(
A = 3.142e-4, 
Cfnom = 0.004, 
Dhyd = 0.02, 
DynamicMomentum = false, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
H = 0, 
HydraulicCapacitance = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Upstream, 
L = 6.6, 
N = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
dpnom = 1000, 
hstartin = 2962.1e3, 
hstartout = 2962.1e3, 
omega = 0.0628, 
pstart = 96e5, 
wnf = 0.1, 
wnom = 0.06)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {40, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkPressure Sink(
p0 = 95e5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {100, 50}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

inner ThermoPower.System system annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, 90}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput DrumPressure annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, -10}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, 
-10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput DrumLevel annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, -38}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, 
-38}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Valve_Opening annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 80}, extent = {{8, 
-8}, {-8, 8}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {90, 80}, extent 
= {{8, -8}, {-8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE SH(
Cfnom_F = 0.01, 
Cfnom_G = 0.01, 
FFtype_F = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
Kfnom_F = 0, 
Kfnom_G = 0, 
N_F = 2, 
N_G = 2, 
Tstartbar_G(displayUnit = "K") = 787.72, 
dpnom_F = 100, 
dpnom_G = 100, 
exchSurface_F = 2.752, 
exchSurface_G = 2.752, 
extSurfaceTub = 5.504, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 21.5, 
fluidNomPressure = 1e+07, 
fluidVol = 0.01376, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.01376, 
lambda = 19, 
metalVol = 0.01376, 
pstart_F = 1e+07, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rhonom_F(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 997, 
rhonom_G = 1)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, 50}, extent = {{10, 
-10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SourceMassFlow Source_FlueGas(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, 
T = 514.57 + 273.15, Xnom = {0.23, 0.02, 0.01, 0.04, 0.7}, 
p0 = 101325, 
w0 = 167.755)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 90}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Economizer(
Cfnom_F = 0.01, 
Cfnom_G = 0.01, 
FFtype_G = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
Kfnom_G = 0, 
N_F = 2, 
N_G = 2, 
Tstartbar_G = 604.74, 
dpnom_F = 100, 
dpnom_G = 100, 
exchSurface_F = 2.752, 
exchSurface_G = 2.752, 
extSurfaceTub = 5.504, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 21.5,
fluidNomPressure = 1e+07, 
fluidVol = 0.01376, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.01376, 
lambda = 19, 
metalVol = 0.01376, 
pstart_F = 1e+07, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rhonom_F(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 997, 
rhonom_G = 1)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-132, 0}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

ThermoPower.Water.Flow1DFV2ph Pipe2DrumFeed(
A = 3.301e-4, 
Cfnom = 0.004, 
Dhyd = 0.0205, 
DynamicMomentum = false, 
FFtype = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.FFtypes.Cfnom, 
FluidPhaseStart = ThermoPower.Choices.FluidPhase.FluidPhases.Liquid, 
H = 0, 
HydraulicCapacitance = ThermoPower.Choices.Flow1D.HCtypes.Downstream, 
L = 10, 
N = 2, 
Nt = 1, 
dpnom = 2000,
hstartin = 1407.6e3, 
hstartout = 1407.6e3, 
omega = 0.0644, 
pstart = 100e5, 
wnom = 0.06)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-96, 0}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Thermal.MetalTubeFV Pipe2DrumFeed_Wall(
L = 11.480, 
Nw = 1, 
Tstart1 = 584.25, 
TstartN = 584.25, 
WallRes = true, 
lambda = 19, 
rext = 0.01305, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rint = 0.01025)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-96, 16}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

ThermoPower.Gas.SinkPressure Sink_FlueGas(
redeclare package Medium = ThermoPower.Media.FlueGas, T = 185.25 + 273.15, 
Xnom = {0.23, 0.02, 0.01, 0.04, 0.7}, 
p0 = 101325)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-122, 34}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SourceMassFlow Source_Water(
T = 46.45 + 273.15, 
h = 203.22e3, 
p0 = 100.0e5, 
use_T = true, 
w0 = 21.5)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-164, 0}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE Risers(
Cfnom_F = 0.01, 
Cfnom_G = 0.01, 
Kfnom_F = 0, 
Kfnom_G = 0, 
N_F = 2, 
N_G = 2, 
Tstartbar_G(displayUnit = "K") = 760.17, 
dpnom_F = 100, 
dpnom_G = 100, 
exchSurface_F = 2.752, 
exchSurface_G = 2.752, 
extSurfaceTub = 5.504, 
fluidNomFlowRate = 21.5, 
fluidNomPressure = 1e+07, 
fluidVol = 0.01376, 
gasNomFlowRate = 169.755, 
gasNomPressure = 101325, 
gasVol = 0.01376, 
lambda = 19, 
metalVol = 0.01376, 
pstart_F = 1e+07, 
pstart_G = 101325, 
rhomcm = 4.08e6, 
rhonom_F(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 997, 
rhonom_G = 1)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {72, -72}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

equation
connect(Valve_Opening, VaporValve.theta) annotation(
Line(points = {{90, 80}, {70, 80}, {70, 58}}, color = {0, 0, 127}, 
thickness = 0.75));
connect(Pipe2Drum_Wall.int, Pipe2Drum.wall) annotation(
Line(points = {{19, 6}, {19, -4.3}}, color = {255, 127, 0}, thickness = 
0.75));
connect(Downcomer.wall, Downcomer_Wall.int) annotation(
Line(points = {{-59, -50}, {-51, -50}}, color = {255, 127, 0}, thickness = 
0.75));
connect(Pipe2Valve_Wall.int, Pipe2Valve.wall) annotation(
Line(points = {{40, 63}, {40, 55}}, color = {255, 127, 0}, thickness = 
0.75));
connect(Pipe2SH_Wall.int, Pipe2SH.wall) annotation(
Line(points = {{-20, 63}, {-20, 56}}, color = {255, 127, 0}, thickness = 
0.75));
connect(Pipe2DrumFeed_Wall.int, Pipe2DrumFeed.wall) annotation(
Line(points = {{-96, 13}, {-96, 6}}, color = {255, 127, 0}, thickness = 
0.75));
connect(HeaderUpper.outlet, Pipe2Drum.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{72, -26}, {72, -9.5}, {30, -9.5}, {30, -9}}, color = {0, 
0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Pipe2Drum.outfl, Drum.riser) annotation(
Line(points = {{8, -9}, {-33, -9}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Drum.steam, Pipe2SH.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{-37, 18}, {-36.82, 18}, {-36.82, 49.7}, {-30.82, 49.7}}, 
color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(SH.gasOut, Risers.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{10, 40}, {10, 40}, {10, 20}, {92, 20}, {92, -72}, {82, 
-72}, {82, -72}}, color = {159, 159, 223}, thickness = 0.75));
connect(Risers.gasOut, Economizer.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{62, -72}, {-132, -72}, {-132, -10}, {-132, -10}}, color = 
{159, 159, 223}, thickness = 0.75));
connect(HeaderUpper.inlet, Risers.waterOut) annotation(
Line(points = {{72, -46}, {72, -46}, {72, -62}, {72, -62}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}, thickness = 1));
connect(PressureDrop.outlet, Risers.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{48, -96}, {72, -96}, {72, -82}, {72, -82}, {72, -82}}, 
color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Economizer.gasOut, Sink_FlueGas.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{-132, 10}, {-132, 10}, {-132, 34}, {-132, 34}}, color = 
{159, 159, 223}, thickness = 0.75));
connect(Blowdown.flange, Drum.blowdown) annotation(
Line(points = {{-20, -32}, {-49, -32}, {-49, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, 
thickness = 1));
connect(Source_Water.flange, Economizer.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-154, 0}, {-142, 0}, {-142, 0}, {-142, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Economizer.waterOut, Pipe2DrumFeed.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{-122, 0}, {-106, 0}, {-106, 0}, {-106, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Pipe2DrumFeed.outfl, Drum.feedwater) annotation(
Line(points = {{-86, 0}, {-69, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Drum.downcomer, Downcomer.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{-64, -12}, {-64, -12}, {-64, -40}, {-64, -40}}, color = 
{0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Downcomer.outfl, HeaderLower.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-64, -60}, {-64, -96}, {-40, -96}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, 
thickness = 1));
connect(Source_FlueGas.flange, SH.gasIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{10, 90}, {10, 90}, {10, 60}, {10, 60}, {10, 60}, {10, 
60}}, color = {159, 159, 223}, thickness = 0.75));
connect(Pipe2SH.outfl, SH.waterIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-10, 50}, {0, 50}, {0, 50}, {0, 50}, {0, 50}, {0, 50}}, 
color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(SH.waterOut, Pipe2Valve.infl) annotation(
Line(points = {{20, 50}, {30, 50}, {30, 50}, {30, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}, thickness = 1));
connect(VaporValve.outlet, Sink.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{80, 50}, {90, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(Pipe2Valve.outfl, VaporValve.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{50, 50}, {60, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 1));
connect(HeaderLower.outlet, PressureDrop.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-20, -96}, {28, -96}}, color = {0, 0, 255}, thickness = 
1));
DrumPressure = Drum.p;
DrumLevel = Drum.y;
annotation(
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));end 
HRSG_WaterDrum_HXVersion;
```

Comment: Questions are best suited for Stack Overflow when they are concrete. I don't see any model attached, and don't know what the issue at hand is.

Comment: I was concerned supplying the whole source code might intimidate users from trouble shooting . . . But thanks for inquiring! I made an update and supplied my models code above. Please let me know how I can go about trouble shooting the errors or if I should refer to any good resources on how to debug a modelica model :)

Answer (score 7):

Running that model (at least with the version of ThermoPower I had) stops immediately with:

> Error: The following error was detected at time: 0   External radius
>   must be greater than internal radius   Failed condition:
>   SH.metalTube.rext > 0.01

The cause is that ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.HE has:

```
 Thermal.MetalTubeFV metalTube(
    rint=fluidVol*4/exchSurface_F/2,
    rext=(metalVol + fluidVol)*4/extSurfaceTub/2,
```

and you set `extSurfaceTub` twice as large as `exchSurface_F` for `SH`, `Economizer`, and `Risers`.

**In general** I would say the first step is asking **Why are you debugging the model?**

1. Did it fail to initialize?
2. Did it initialize, but then the simulation stopped at some time?
3. Does it run, but generate the wrong results?
4. Does it run and generate the right results as far as you can tell, but too slowly?

Otherwise I don't why you would debug at all.

The first step in debugging any model is then:

- **Look at the warnings during translation**
- Check that the model components are tested
- Check that they are connected together in the right way and with suitable parameters

Correcting the previous errors stops the model during initialization, but there were two kinds of warnings in Dymola that indicates problems that should be corrected:

The initial conditions are not fully specified.
Dymola has selected default initial conditions.

Assuming fixed start value for the continuous states:

> Economizer.fluidFlow.htilde[] 
>   Economizer.gasFlow.Xtilde[]
>   Risers.fluidFlow.htilde[] 
>   Risers.gasFlow.Xtilde[] 
>   SH.gasFlow.p(start = SH.gasFlow.pstart) 
>   SH.gasFlow.Xtilde[]

Conflicting start values

The start value of the variable Economizer.fluidFlow.htilde[1] being Pipe2DrumFeed.hstart[1] has been selected as a default initial condition.
However, the start value has been selected from a set of alias variables having conflicting start values of the same precedence.
1407600.0, the start value of Pipe2DrumFeed.h[1] given as Pipe2DrumFeed.hstart[1].
100000.0, the start value of Economizer.fluidFlow.htilde[1] given as Economizer.fluidFlow.hstart[2].

The iteration variable SH.fluidFlow.htilde[1] has been selected to have the guess value Pipe2Valve.hstart[1].
However, the start value has been selected from a set of alias variables having conflicting start values of the same precedence.
2962100.0, the start value of Pipe2Valve.h[1] given as Pipe2Valve.hstart[1].
100000.0, the start value of SH.fluidFlow.htilde[1] given as SH.fluidFlow.hstart[2].

The iteration variable HeaderUpper.p has been selected to have the guess value HeaderUpper.pstart.
However, the start value has been selected from a set of alias variables having conflicting start values of the same precedence.
10020000.0, the start value of HeaderUpper.p given as HeaderUpper.pstart.
10000000.0, the start value of Pipe2Drum.p given as Pipe2Drum.pstart.

The iteration variable VaporValve.w has been selected to have the guess value VaporValve.wnom.
However, the start value has been selected from a set of alias variables having conflicting start values of the same precedence.
0.12, the start value of VaporValve.inlet.m_flow given as VaporValve.wnom.
-0.12, the start value of VaporValve.outlet.m_flow given as -VaporValve.wnom.
-0.06, the start value of Pipe2Valve.outfl.m_flow given as -Pipe2Valve.wnom.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response/thinking strategy for debugging.

Comment: I'm confused with what you said about Economizer.fluidFlow.htilde[1]
First of all, am I over constraining the system by entering enthalpy values for Pipe2DrumFeed.hstartin/hstartout? I entered these values trying to define the systems enthalpy to be THAT value at that point, exiting the Economizer.HE based on hand calculations.
Also, the start value that has been selected from a "set of alias variables" ... why was the start value chosen as Economizer.FluidFlow.Hstart[2]? Also, how can you located this information? Location of chosen Variables?

Comment: As for the pressure of HeaderUpper.p, at the time I was giving my model parameters, I was loosely following a Modelica library example that has pressure fluctuations like this within the downers/headers. In general, should I not follow the behavior of parameters within library models? Also curious as to how you are able to locate and identify what components are using what variables, when they are guessing and when they using a suggested start value.

Comment: The last section of advice you gave has me the most confused. I'm having trouble understanding what you said and giving it meaning to what my model is doing incorrectly? If you can elaborate this idea a little bit, maybe relate it to one of the other issues you pointed out, I think that could give the coding error some relevant context for me to understand! Thanks @HansOlsson.

Comment: Finally, did you plug my source code into the Dymola application? I've been slowly learning that Dymola is a much user friendly modeling program when compared to OpenModelica . . . Is that how you're able to identify these specific error messges? I find it rather difficult to (1) interpret the error message and (2) logically move forward with diagnosing and solving the error message.

i.e. I've never seen such a straight forward error message as:
Error: The following error was detected at time: 0 External radius must be greater than internal radius Failed condition: SH.metalTube.rext > 0.01

Comment: @NRELintern the conflicting start values appear because you have connected several components together, and you have not specified which start-value to use. The first step is to just check if the selected values make sense, in that case there is no need to do anything. For "start values" you could use "fixed=true" to indicate that one of them should be the real start value, an alternative (that also works for "iteration variables") is to additionally set the start-value at top of the model - since that should have higher precedence.

Comment: Is it wrong to assign components their calculated value i.e. enthalpy or pressure, after the start-value top of the model has already been given the system start value? Is this modeling strategy in-correct? - because my intention was to establish defined states with specific boundary conditions i.e. enthalpy and pressure levels.Also, is there a difference between "start value" and "nominal value"? Does one conflict the other?

Comment: Without good start-values the model may not start  so that strategy might not work. And there is a large difference between "start value" and "nominal value". The nominal value is just an indication of the magnitude of the value for scaling purposes; such as 1e5 for pressure (regardless of whether the pressure is 1.1e5 or 2e5) - whereas a start-value means that something actually starts at that exact value.

Comment: *I've never seen such a straight forward error message as: Error: The following error was detected at time: 0 External radius must be greater than internal radius Failed condition: SH.metalTube.rext > 0.01*  to be honest I am surprised by this, this comes from a normal `assert` check within `MetalTubeFV`, and in my experience OMEdit shows these messages without problem. I tried to track why this does not happen here, but was unsuccessful.